# While displaying data using foreach loop in MVC asp.net 4 I am not able to get the Name of the selected Item as the paramerter in Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

the code in view which i am dispalying using foreach loop

```
@Url.Action("StartJob", "Batch", new { batchName = @Model.BatchInformationList.ElementAt(i-1).JobName })
```

the code in controller

```
public PartialViewResult StartJob(string batchName)
{
    return this.PartialView(res);
}
```

I am getting data in batchname of last element in the model I am iterating

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this,

```
  @Html.ActionLink("EditUser","StartJob", "Batch",new { batchName = @Model.BatchInformationList.ElementAt(i-1).JobName })
```

in `ActionLink` First paramete is string, second is your page like`StartJob`,  third is controller`Batch`. And this directly redirect to your `action`.

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult StartJob(string batchName )
 {
 return this.PartialView(res);

 }
```

Comment: Hi,
I am using this
var url = "@Html.ActionLink(, ,"StartJob", "Batch","Test", "Test", new { batchName = @Model.BatchInformationList.ElementAt(i-1).JobName })";
but wht to type in the first two parameters my controller name is batch and action name is startjob

Comment: Hi,
I tried this but for the first parameter I am getting cannot convert HTMLMVCSTRING TO string

Comment: can you post your `actionlink` so i can help you.

Comment: hey Thanks for the help I got it now